# How to manipulate buffer in Rust?

Tags: rust

a few weeks ago I got interested in Rust. So far I have only read online tutorials and wonder how to manipulate buffer memory in Rust. Let's say I have C code like this:

```
int main()
{
    char buffer[] = { 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xaa };

    int a = *(int*)&buffer[0];
    a = 0xdeadc0de;

    short b = *(short*)&buffer[4];
    b = 0xbadf;

    *(int*)&buffer[0] = a;  
    *(short*)&buffer[4] = b; 

    //buffer memory: de c0 ad de df ba 77 88 99 aa

    return 0;
}
```

Could anyone write this in Rust please? I think there's no casting in Rust, right?

Comment: Programming requests are usually against the policies of StackOverflow. The usual procedure is that you provide your own attempt and we can tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @Finomnis I agree that it would have been nice to show what they tried in rust, but asking what the idiomatic way to do something like: <code in c>, is an ok question in my book. *As long as it's just a few lines of course*.

Comment: If you think so, then I shall stand corrected :)

Comment: Between the alignment requirements and type-based aliasing, this code is probably unsafe even in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Direct buffer manipulation through transmuted references is considered unsafe in Rust. You *can* of course use the `unsafe` keyword for writing into memory directly, but that would negate the whole safety advantage of using Rust.

You can *create* an `u32`, *convert* it to a `[u8]` array and then write that into the buffer. But you cannot safely get a `&u32` reference from a buffer.

```
fn main() {
    let mut buffer = vec![0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xaa];

    let a: u32 = 0xdeadc0de;
    let a_bytes = a.to_le_bytes();
    buffer[0..4].copy_from_slice(&a_bytes);

    let b: u16 = 0xbadf;
    let b_bytes = b.to_le_bytes();
    buffer[4..6].copy_from_slice(&b_bytes);

    println!("{:x?}", buffer);
}
```

```
[de, c0, ad, de, df, ba, 77, 88, 99, aa]
```

---

Just for reference, this is how this would look like with `unsafe` code.
I highly discourage this solution, though.

```
fn main() {
    let mut buffer: Vec<u8> = vec![0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xaa];

    unsafe {
        let ptr = buffer.as_mut_ptr();

        let a = ptr.offset(0) as *mut u32;
        *a = 0xdeadc0de;

        let b = ptr.offset(4) as *mut u16;
        *b = 0xbadf;
    }

    println!("{:x?}", buffer);
}
```

```
[de, c0, ad, de, df, ba, 77, 88, 99, aa]
```

Note that the `unsafe` solution does **not** behave exactly like the safe solution. It will flip the bytes if compiled on a big-endian architecture.

This is what `to_le_bytes` prevents.